# Algorithm for fast decompression & rescaling of jpeg image

Tags: jpeg, image-scaling, uclinux, rescale

Working on an application in uCLinux 2.4 to run in an IP camera. Need to grab an image from the videostream (MJPEG, MPEG4 or h.264), decompress it to raw format and rescale it to smaller size. Need to do this at 10-15 FPS but the processing capacity is quite limited so must do this in a very optimized way. Assume that the decompression and rescaling should be done in the same move.

Any ideas on where to look for solutions or algorithms? Or an expert that can help us out..?

Answer (score 0):

The work of Guido Vollbeding may help to solve your problem (http://jpegclub.org/djpeg/). The algorithm does decode only the stream and not the whole picture.

Comment: Yes looked at that already, but a bit too heavy algorithms for the platform I am afraid. But problem solved anyway, turned out that it was not that difficult..